# KDE Plasma 5.18.4 Clipboard and Notification Widget clear history button bug

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons, plasma, widgets

I'm having a weird icon in "Clear History" button shown in KDE Plasma 5.18.4 Clipboard widget for my taskbar panel, and also in the Notification Widget, anyone knows how to fix this?

I'm using the Kubuntu Global Theme, and the Breeze Dark Icons

I had a similar issue in Ubuntu 18.04 for some applications after applying a new theme, and the fix was to reinstall the application, but I'm not sure about what to do in this case

Here are some pictures of the bug

[Clipboard Widget Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUUja.png)

[Notification Widget Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKGyd.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you hovered the mouse/trackpad pointer over the icon when there are items in the clipboard or pending notifications, you'd see a tooltip appear: "Clear History". What is the problem?

Comment: The problem was just the icon, it was not showing correctly as I show in the screenshots, I just found the fix and answered my own question to help if somebody has the same problem, thank you for your concern

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, it's the intended icon. It's a broom that cleans/clears the list of items.

If you don't like it you're free to choose another icon theme.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching the icon set to another (for example Vimix)

Now it looks like this

[Fixed icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC8FV.png)